WebAssembly wait & notify not working across wasi threads
I'm trying to make a thread_join function in WebAssembly by setting a mutex to 1 in the main thread, and then launching a thread. the thread unlocks its mutex before exiting. the main thread can get notified with the threads exit by trying to acquire the mutex and releasing it.
This is my code:
(module
  (type $main_type (func))
  (type $simple_type (func (param i32)))
  (type $thread_spawn_type (func (param i32) (result i32)))
  (type $thread_start_type (func (param i32 i32)))
  (import "wasi" "thread-spawn" (func $thread_spawn (type $thread_spawn_type)))
  (func $try_lock_mutex (type $thread_spawn_type) (param $mutex_address i32) (result i32)
    local.get $mutex_address
    i32.const 0 ;; expected
    i32.const 1 ;; locked
    i32.atomic.rmw.cmpxchg
    i32.eqz
  )
   (func $lock_mutex (type $simple_type) (param $mutex_address i32)
      block $done
        loop $retry
          ;; Try to lock the mutex. $tryLockMutex returns 1 if the mutex
          ;; was locked, and 0 otherwise.
          local.get $mutex_address
          call $try_lock_mutex
          br_if $done
          ;; Wait for the other agent to finish with mutex.
          local.get $mutex_address ;; mutex address
          i32.const 1              ;; expected value (1 => locked)
          i64.const -1             ;; infinite timeout
          memory.atomic.wait32
          drop
          br $retry
        end
      end
   )
  (func $unlock_mutex (type $simple_type) (param $mutex_address i32)
      ;; mutex must be locked before by caller
      ;; Unlock the mutex.
      local.get $mutex_address     ;; mutex address
      i32.const 0              ;; 0 => unlocked
      i32.atomic.store

      ;; Notify one agent that is waiting on this lock.
      local.get $mutex_address   ;; mutex address
      i32.const 1            ;; notify 1 waiter
      memory.atomic.notify
      drop
   )
  (func $wait_mutex_lock (type $simple_type) (param $mutex_address i32)
    local.get $mutex_address
    call $lock_mutex
    local.get $mutex_address
    call $unlock_mutex
  )
  (func $wasi_thread_start (type $thread_start_type) (param i32 i32)
     local.get 1
     call $unlock_mutex
  )
  (func $main (type $main_type)
    i32.const 0
    call $lock_mutex
    i32.const 0
    call $thread_spawn
    drop
    i32.const 0
    call $wait_mutex_lock
  )
  (memory (;0;) 4 4 shared)
  (export "wasi_thread_start" (func $wasi_thread_start))
  (export "_start" (func $main))
)

I convert it to wasm using wat2wasm like this:
wat2wasm.exe mutex.wat --enable-threads -o mutex.wasm

Then run it using wasmtime with:
wasmtime -W all-proposals=y -S threads .\mutex.wasm

The mutex code is from the wasm-threads proposal.
The problem is that the mutex never gets unlocked by the launched thread and the main thread gets stuck in an infinite waiting state.

I just found what is wrong with the code above. you need to import & export memory + explecitly specify atomic operation memory index for it to work.
Here is new working code:
(module
  (type $main_type (func))
  (type $simple_type (func (param i32)))
  (type $thread_spawn_type (func (param i32) (result i32)))
  (type $thread_start_type (func (param i32 i32)))
  (import "env" "memory" (memory (;0;) 4 4 shared))
  (import "wasi" "thread-spawn" (func $thread_spawn (type $thread_spawn_type)))
  (func $try_lock_mutex (type $thread_spawn_type) (param $mutex_address i32) (result i32)
    local.get $mutex_address
    i32.const 0 ;; expected
    i32.const 1 ;; locked
    i32.atomic.rmw.cmpxchg 0
    i32.eqz
  )
   (func $lock_mutex (type $simple_type) (param $mutex_address i32)
      block $done
        loop $retry
          ;; Try to lock the mutex. $tryLockMutex returns 1 if the mutex
          ;; was locked, and 0 otherwise.
          local.get $mutex_address
          call $try_lock_mutex
          br_if $done
          ;; Wait for the other agent to finish with mutex.
          local.get $mutex_address ;; mutex address
          i32.const 1              ;; expected value (1 => locked)
          i64.const -1             ;; infinite timeout
          memory.atomic.wait32 0
          drop
          br $retry
        end
      end
   )
  (func $unlock_mutex (type $simple_type) (param $mutex_address i32)
      ;; mutex must be locked before by caller
      ;; Unlock the mutex.
      local.get $mutex_address     ;; mutex address
      i32.const 0              ;; 0 => unlocked
      i32.atomic.store 0

      ;; Notify one agent that is waiting on this lock.
      local.get $mutex_address   ;; mutex address
      i32.const 1            ;; notify 1 waiter
      memory.atomic.notify 0
      drop
   )
  (func $wait_mutex_lock (type $simple_type) (param $mutex_address i32)
    local.get $mutex_address
    call $lock_mutex
    local.get $mutex_address
    call $unlock_mutex
  )
  (func $wasi_thread_start (type $thread_start_type) (param i32 i32)
     local.get 1
     call $unlock_mutex
  )
  (func $main (type $main_type)
    i32.const 0
    call $lock_mutex
    i32.const 0
    call $thread_spawn
    drop
    i32.const 0
    call $wait_mutex_lock
  )
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "wasi_thread_start" (func $wasi_thread_start))
  (export "_start" (func $main))
)

and tested with:
wat2wasm.exe mutex.wat --enable-multi-memory --enable-threads -o mutex.wasm
wasmtime -W all-proposals=y -S threads .\mutex.wasm

